# view of raw HTML code, which returns the function in Flask Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, response

I need to return the function `notification_view` displays the html code.
I use `Response`, but it returns the result as a template, but not in html code.

```
from flask import Response 

def notification_view(user_id, notification_id):
        """ View notification of user """
        notification = Notification.query.filter(Notification.unique_id == notification_id,
                                                 Notification.user_id == user_id).first_or_404()

        return Response(notification.render('mail'), mimetype='text/html')
```

`notification_view` function transmits information in the `render` method that is in a `class Notifikation`.

```
class Notification(db.Model):
    unique_id = db.Column(db.String(255), primary_key=True)
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("user.id")
    type = db.Column(db.String(60))


    def render(self, purpose):
        notification_meta = NOTIFICATIONS.get(self.type)
        if purpose == "mail" and "mail" in notification_meta:
            return render_template(notification_meta["mail"], **render_data)
```

I see:
[image]

But I need but I need to be displayed html code of the message

`html style="padding: 0; margin: 0"> <body style="padding: 0; margin: 0"> <table width="100%" border="0" style="border-collapse: collapse; font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;"> <tr> <td align="left" width="50%" valign="middle" style="background-color: #3c8dbc; height: 40px; color: white; padding-left: 10px;"> <span style="font-size:20px;">App</span> <span style="font-size:16px;"> Password Recovery</span> </td> <td align="right" width="50%" valign="middle" style="background-color: #3c8dbc; height: 40px; font-size:14px; padding-right: 10px;"><a style="color: white;" >Login to dashboard</a></td> </tr> <tr> <td colspan="2" style="padding: 10px; font-size: 16px;"> <p>Dear John Lee,</p> <p>A password reset has been requested for this account. <a h>Visit this link</a> and enter your new password. </p> <p>If you did not request a password reset, please ignore and delete this e-mail.</p> <p>Please note: The request will expire in 24 hours.</p> </td> </tr> <tr> <td colspan="2" style="padding: 10px; font-size: 16px; font-style: italic; color: #3c8dbc; "> Kind regards,<br> App Support </td> </tr> </table> </body> </html>`

Comment: What does "as a template, but not in html code" mean? What exactly do you see?

Comment: And what's your problem exactly ? What did you try that didn't work ?

Comment: @DanielRoseman  I've updated the question

Comment: I still don't understand. If you need the raw HTML you can use "view source" in the browser, no?

Comment: No, I need the raw HTML without use "view source" in the browser

Comment: change the mimetype to 'text' ?

Comment: @MauriceMeyer Yes, I change mimetype to 'text' and to 'html', but to no avail

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I change `html` to `plain` in `mimetype`

```
 return Response(notification.render('mail'),mimetype='text/plain')
```